# Compare current row with all previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For `df`:

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       X
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       M
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O       I
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       N
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       I
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       I
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I       I
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       I
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

with reproducible example:

```
data = {'id': [13710750, 13710760, 13710770, 13710780, 13667449, 13667450, 13728171, 13667452],
        'Date': ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-03', '2019-09-03', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-02', '2019-09-17', '2019-08-02'],
        'ITEM_ID': ['SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', '887643', '792184', 'SLM607', '794580'],
        'TYPE': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'O'],
        'GROUP': ['X', 'M', 'I','N','I','I','I', 'I']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to loop through `ITEM_ID` by comparing the current element in `ITEM_ID` with all rows prior to check if there is any row(s) that satisfy conditions below:

(1) has same `ITEM_ID` as current row; and

(2) if that current row has `TYPE== I` and the previous row in (1) has `TYPE== O`, then delete both rows.

What is an efficient way to do this?

---

Tried:

```
l = [test.loc[x,'ITEM_ID'] in test.loc[0:x,'ITEM_ID'].tolist() for x in np.arange(0,len(test))]
test['New']=l
test
```

to filter rows with same 'ITEM_ID' but ended up with `True` for every single row. I am not sure what went wrong and if this is the correct approach.

---

Update:

@Reza's solution

```
df.groupby('ITEM_ID')['TYPE'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'I') & (x.shift() == 'O'))
```

seemed to work. I would like to add an additional condition, ie., same `GROUP`.

Tried:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift()))]
```

but caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-f68c5ffc70cc> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift()))]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1765 
   1766             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1767             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1768 
   1769     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1912         elif com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 1913             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1914         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
   1915 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getbool_axis(self, key, axis)
   1779         # caller is responsible for ensuring non-None axis
   1780         labels = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
-> 1781         key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
   1782         inds = key.nonzero()[0]
   1783         return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in check_bool_indexer(index, key)
   2311     result = key
   2312     if isinstance(key, ABCSeries) and not key.index.equals(index):
-> 2313         result = result.reindex(index)
   2314         mask = isna(result._values)
   2315         if mask.any():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in reindex(self, index, **kwargs)
   4028     @Appender(generic.NDFrame.reindex.__doc__)
   4029     def reindex(self, index=None, **kwargs):
-> 4030         return super().reindex(index=index, **kwargs)
   4031 
   4032     def drop(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4542         # perform the reindex on the axes
   4543         return self._reindex_axes(
-> 4544             axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
   4545         ).__finalize__(self)
   4546 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   4557             ax = self._get_axis(a)
   4558             new_index, indexer = ax.reindex(
-> 4559                 labels, level=level, limit=limit, tolerance=tolerance, method=method
   4560             )
   4561 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in reindex(self, target, method, level, limit, tolerance)
   2423             else:
   2424                 # hopefully?
-> 2425                 target = MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
   2426 
   2427         if (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in from_tuples(cls, tuples, sortorder, names)
    487                 tuples = tuples._values
    488 
--> 489             arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
    490         elif isinstance(tuples, list):
    491             arrays = list(lib.to_object_array_tuples(tuples).T)

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
```

Comment: can you provide the code to generate the dataframe for faster response

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: Hi @Reza please see edited question

Comment: Hi @gtomer please see edited question

Comment: in your dataframe for each `ITEM_ID` you have only 2 rows or it could be more?

Comment: I fixed the solution for your second case, let me know if that's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following which returns a boolean Series:

```
df.groupby('ITEM_ID')['TYPE'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'I') & (x.shift() == 'O'))
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: TYPE, dtype: bool
```

For the second case, you can use:

```
myfilter = lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift())
df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(myfilter).reset_index('ITEM_ID', drop=True).sort_index()
```

Comment: Hi Reza, thank you for the solution - would it be possible to add an additional condition of `GROUP` being the same, by using apply twice or another way?

Comment: I tried `display(df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift())))` which returned boolean data type, but with `df[display(df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift()))])` to filter to dataframe it returned `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'`.

Comment: so you want make the rows you are comparing have the same ITEM_ID and GROUP?

Comment: Yeah, are you saying that I groupby `['ITEM_ID ', 'GROUP']`?

Comment: Takeout display inside df[ ]

Comment: Your code should work too, just remove display from the second comment

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I used `df[df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(lambda x: (x['TYPE'] == 'I') & (x['TYPE'].shift() == 'O') & (x['GROUP'] == x['GROUP'].shift()))]`. Please see edited question.

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: Hi Reza, I think this is what I wanted. Could you please explain why we need `.reset_index('PART_ID', drop=True).sort_index()` in the last part? Also, I used `df[df.groupby('ITEM_ID').apply(myfilter).reset_index('ITEM_ID', drop=True).sort_index()]` to filter the rows with `TYPE == I` but not the corresponding `TYPE == O`. Can we mark both `TYPE == I and TYPE == O` as `True` to filter both values? Thank you.

Comment: Besides, seems like `x['TYPE'].shift()` only compare the immediately row prior but not all rows in front. Can we consider all previous rows?

Comment: can you update your question with more rows, because I thought you have only 2 rows per `ITEM_ID`

Comment: Hi Reza, please see edited question - I have updated the reproducible example. Thank you.