# Compare row with all previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numb': [2,4,6,2,4,9]})
print(df)
   numb
0     2
1     4
2     6
3     2
4     4
5     9
```

I would like to count the number of rows where numb is lesser than the numb of the previous, like

```
   numb  lesser_count
0     2             0
1     4             0
2     6             0
3     2             2
4     4             1
5     9             0
```

I came across a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788778/compare-current-row-with-all-previous-rows) but not sure how to take the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try numpy broadcasting:

```
a = df['numb'].to_numpy()

df['lesser_count'] = np.triu(a<a[:,None]).sum(0)
```

Output:

```
   numb  lesser_count
0     2             0
1     4             0
2     6             0
3     2             2
4     4             1
5     9             0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `numba` for a fast for loop implementation:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def count_lesser(arr):
    counts = np.empty(arr.shape[0])
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        counts[i] = np.sum(val < arr[:i])
    return counts


df['lesser_count'] = count_lesser(df['numb'].to_numpy())
print(df)
```

```py
   numb  lesser_count
0     2             0
1     4             0
2     6             0
3     2             2
4     4             1
5     9             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we'll need an iterative solution here or to rely on potentially memory inefficient numpy based approaches, `numba` is a good option:

```
from numba import njit, int64
@njit('int64[:](int64[:])')
def lesser_prev(a):
    out = np.empty(len(a), dtype=int64)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        curr = a[i]
        for j in range(i):
            if curr<a[j]:
                count+=1
        out[i] = count
        count = 0
    return out
```

---

```
df['lesser_count'] = lesser_prev(df.numb.to_numpy())

print(df)
   numb  lesser_count
0     2             0
1     4             0
2     6             0
3     2             2
4     4             1
5     9             0
```

Check on performace:

```
df_ = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index()

%timeit lesser_prev(df_.numb.to_numpy())
# 15.2 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit count_lesser(df_['numb'].to_numpy())
# 15.3 ms ± 132 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
a = df_['numb'].to_numpy()
np.triu(a<a[:,None]).sum(0)
# 280 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```